# not detecting number of whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to enable inputs to accept any number of whitelines after the ")" bracket. I have looked up regex websites and "\s+" should do the job, but in my example it doesn't work.

Here's what I got:

```
String data5 = "Relation(Attribute)           ";
String regexAlt = "([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9,-_ ]+\\)+[\n|\\s\n|\\s+])+";
if(data5.matches(regexAlt)){
    System.out.println("yes");
}
    else{
        System.out.println("No");
}
```

It keeps outputting "no".
Any suggestions?

Comment: try replacing [\n|\\s\n|\\s+])+ with \s+ and also remove first (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
String regexAlt = "([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9,-_ ]+\\)+[\\n\\r\\s]+)";
                                                            ^  ^  ^ ^
```

Comment: thank you soo much. I like to ask, how come it's [\\n\\r\\s]+ ?? does it work the same as using "|" ?

Comment: if you use characterclass `[]` then you do not need to use pipe(`|`) inside that. Also, you didn't use `+` immeaditely after the `[]` that's why your regex didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

This one works just fine ..

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("(\\d+|\\w+)\\W?\\w+\\W?\\s+").matcher(data5).matches());
```

Comment: Prints out `True` which is what you want.